# difference registerForContextMenu and setOnCreateContextMenuListener?

Tags: android, menu

what's the difference between registerForContextMenu :

> Registers a context menu to be shown for the given view (multiple views can show the context menu). This method will set the View.OnCreateContextMenuListener on the view to this activity
>
> Call registerForContextMenu() and pass it the View you want to give a context menu. **When this View then receives a long-press**, it displays a context menu.

and setOnCreateContextMenuListener :

> Register a callback to be invoked when the context menu for this view is being built. **If this view is not long clickable**, it becomes long clickable.

which one to use? and about the long clickable stuff : both are doing the same thing...

Thanks

Comment: Looks like they're the same thing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When in doubt... look at the Android source code! It is open source, after all. :)

**git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git/core/java/android/view/View.java:**

```
/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when the context menu for this view is
 * being built. If this view is not long clickable, it becomes long clickable.
 *
 * @param l The callback that will run
 *
 */
public void setOnCreateContextMenuListener(OnCreateContextMenuListener l) {
    if (!isLongClickable()) {
        setLongClickable(true);
    }
    mOnCreateContextMenuListener = l;
}
```

**git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git/core/java/android/app/Activity.java:**

```
/**
 * Registers a context menu to be shown for the given view (multiple views
 * can show the context menu). This method will set the
 * {@link OnCreateContextMenuListener} on the view to this activity, so
 * {@link #onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu, View, ContextMenuInfo)} will be
 * called when it is time to show the context menu.
 *
 * @see #unregisterForContextMenu(View)
 * @param view The view that should show a context menu.
 */
public void registerForContextMenu(View view) {
    view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
}
```

So, the answer is that they're the same. `registerForContextMenu()` does nothing except invoke `setOnCreateContextMenuListener()`.

Comment: mmh thanks, i've never tried to look at the source code, in any languages, i'm afraid to be lost after just a few seconds, but well, i'll have a look next time! thanks for your answer! Cheers!

Comment: answer to which there can be no requestioning.. perfect, @Trevor Johns. Also, it shows the way to tackle other similar type of questions/doubts.